# How to invoke some action on a component from the outside?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

I am building a simple feedback collection component for VuePress. I "packaged" it as a plugin, because that's the proper way to do that I suppose.
The plugin is very simple and consists of:

- `FeedbackCollector.vue` - a Vue component that displays a feedback button at the bottom of a page. When clicked, a panel appears with a few questions for the user
- `index.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    name: 'feedback-flyout',
    enhanceAppFiles: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'enhanceAppFile.js')
    ],
    globalUIComponents: 'FeedbackCollector'
}
```

- `enhanceAppFile.js`:

```js
import FeedbackCollector from './FeedbackCollector.vue'

export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.component('FeedbackCollector', FeedbackCollector)
}
```

With this set of files, I have the basic functionality:  my component is displayed on every page of my VuePress site.
Now, the thing is that I'd like to be able to open the feedback panel automatically sometimes, without the user clicking the button. I would add a method to my component `openPanel`. How do I invoke that method from the outside? That "outside" would probably be another JS file in my plugin that would check some cookies, and open the panel if the user has never seen that before.

How to do that?

1. How to add that new JS file to my plugin? I mean, how to make the code in this file run when my site loads? How to make it run whenever user navigates to a different document on my site?
2. How to invoke the `openPanel` method that is defined in `FeedbackCollector.vue` from that new file?

Or maybe there is some other better way to do that than what I proposed?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

1. To perform the check, I think you can use [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks). For example, you can trigger the check function every time your Vue instance is updated.

The lifecycle hooks are defined in the `enhanceApp.js` file. Details on it are in the [documentation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/basic-config.html#app-level-enhancements).

For instance, to define the updated hook I commented above, you can code your `enhanceApp.js` file as

```
export default ({ Vue, options }) => {
  options['updated'] = function () {
    // your check function
  }
}
```

2. I think you can solve this by defining a state variable into your Vue instance, and methods to set and read this variable. Your check function will set the variable state. And your component will read the variable and open/close the panel accordingly. The [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) provides a simple example of state management.

To define the state variable and the methods to manage it you can read the [documentation on data and methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods). Remember that the Vue instance is available on vuepress in the `enhanceApp.js` file. To access the Vue instance inside the components, [call the `$root` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance).

Comment: Interesting. I think the lifecycle hooks is the right place to register my "checking" function. Regarding the state stuff - it seems that for this to work, I'd have to add the state in `enhanceApp.js` of my vuepress site - this is outside of my plugin, and I'd prefer to keep the plugin "isolated", if you know what I mean. However, I think that a simple solution could be to just artificially click the button that opens the questions panel via JS. Initially I also thought about it, but it seemed a bit hacky - after all I fully control the component, so why would I have to artificially click it.

Comment: I was scanning the documentation and realized that [the plugin API has it own lifecycle configuration](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/life-cycle.html#ready).
On the matter of the `enhanceApp.js` at the plugin level, you can do it by [setting the enhancement app files](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#enhanceappfiles). I think this is sufficient to keep all the code inside the plugin.

Comment: I followed your recommendation about the state. In combination with `Vue.observable` I managed to implement it, and it works very well. Thanks a lot for your suggestion! By the way, I "registered" my check function in the mixin, which I registered using Options API in the plugin. Mixins have lifecycle hooks (created, mounted). First I tried to add these lifecycle hooks under `enhanceApp.js`, but that didn't work for some reason.